# Which out of the two has greater bond angle? Water or diethylether.Why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

**My theory:**

The ethyl groups in diethylether being larger in size when compared to hydrogens in water, should be **repelled more** by the lone pairs on the central atom oxygen. Hence, the ethyl groups should come closer, thereby **decreasing** the bond angle.

Moreover, the electronegativity difference between the central atom and the peripheral atoms is more in case of water i.e., **$\ce{O-H}$ electronegativity difference is more than that in $\ce{C-O}$** as per Pauling’s scale. Hence, the oxygen atom should pull the bond pair closer, thereby allowing to open up the $\ce{H-O-H}$ bond increasing the bond angle.

Hence bond angle of water should be greater than that of diethylether. Am I right?

**PS:** I know that in reality dimethylether has greater bond angle than water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mostly correct with your reasoning , and the $\ce{C-O-C}$ bond angle was indeed expected to be lesser than that of $\ce{H-O-H}$ bond angle of water . But it's all theoretical. Experimentally the opposite was observed and was explained on the basis of steric hindrance or steric repulsion of the two bulky $\ce{C2H5}$ groups.

In case of $\ce{(C2H5)2O}$, the positive deviation of the bond angle can be explained on the basis of steric crowding of two ethyl groups. They repel each other and as a result , they do not let the lone pairs of Oxygen compress the bond angle more .

$\ce{H-O-H}$ bond angle is found to be $104.5^\circ$ whereas the $\ce{C-O-C}$ bond angle in diethyl ether is found to be roughly close to $110.5^\circ$. It can be attributed to the steric repulsion that trumps the bond pair-bond pair and lone pair-lone pair repulsion in this case.